# Set default page in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC+Razor Pages+Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to use MVC, Razor Pages & Web API within the same project. How do I set the default page to go to a MVC view and not a Razor Page? The default page should go to `~/Views/ToDo/Index.cshtml` and not `~/Pages/Index.cshtml`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Deleted for brevity ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=ToDo}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change the routing of Index.cshtml in razor page.

Here is a demo:

Pages/index.cshtml(When you want to go to Pages/index.cshtml,route need to be `https://localhost:xxxx/Index1`):

```
@page "Index1"
@model xxxxxxx.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
```

/Views/ToDo/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>TodoIndex</h1>
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Deleted for brevity ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Todo}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
}
```

result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Yiyi You!  The solution here is to rename the default Razor page @page "Index1".  It doesn't matter if endpoints.MapRazorPages() is placed before or after endpoints.MapControllerRoute(...) and services.AddMvc() has the same implementation as services.AddControllersWithViews() & services.AddRazorPages() as documented here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0303c9e90b5b48b309a78c2ec9911db1812e6bf3/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution would be to delete or rename the actual file at `/Pages/Index.cshtml`. The only reason that a route `"/"` is created to it is because it exists. If you remove or rename the file, no route will be generated.

Comment: Obviously, I forgot that Index is the default page in Razor Pages, but I'm still puzzled as to why the order of the endpoints (MapRazorPages / MapControllerRoute) doesn't affect the selection of the default page.